# Using crontab to execute script between 17:00–20:00 for every 10 minutes

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, command, cron

I want to send emails to clients every day **between 17:00 to 20:00.** I want to run my command **every 10 minutes in this period.**
So the script will be executed 6 times per hour. That's a total of 18 times.

Is this possible with the crontab? How should I write the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
0/10 17-19 * * *  <cmd>
```

or:

```
0/10 17,18,19 * * * <cmd>
```

Comment: The second is correct. The first will run at 20:10, 20:20, etc. If you want it to run at 20:00 then you should add another entry just for that.